# How to assert App::make is not called in laravel with phpunit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-6

I have a class thats role is to loop through database records and create instances of the class names it finds. Each of these classes is created using App::make(). I would like to unit test this function but i cant find a way to assert app::make is never called.

```
class Switcher
{
    public function process($foo)
    {
        $classes = Classes::where('active')->get();

        foreach ($classes as $class) {
            if($foo->bar >= $class->bar) {
                $instance = \App::make($class->class_name);
                $instance->handle($foo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything call with `make()`, you can make it return your own instances. This can be a mocked object.

```
public testNotCalled() {
    $class = factory(Classes::class)->create();

    $this->instance($class->class_name, function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldNotReceive('handle');
    });

    // call your endpoint etc.
}
```

But in general assertion something not to happen can be fuzzy. As you code can not work and the assertions will still pass.

Comment: Was hoping to have a more general make not called but this seems to be the best option